# sql query doesn't work in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query which run well in SQLyog but not in eclipse. The error showed is "Column not found" when I debugged.

Here is my query:

```
String searchQuery = "select AVG(Rating) from rating where CoursesID=? and MONTH(dtDate)=? group by dtDate";
```

table:

```
ID     | CoursesID | Rating | Comment | dtDate

11111  | SKM3207   | 5      | No      | 2015-05-20
```

java

```
//preparing some objects for connection 
       Connection currentCon = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
       //double totalRate = 0.0;

       Vector<String> monthRating = new Vector<String>();

       try{
           String searchQuery = "select AVG(Rating) from rating where CoursesID=? and MONTH(dtDate)=? group by dtDate";

           //connect to DB 
           currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
           pstmt=currentCon.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
           pstmt.setString(1, CoursesID);
           pstmt.setString(2, fmonth);
           rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next()){
               monthRating.add(rs.getString("Rating"));
               //String avg = rs.getString(1);
               //totalRate = Double.parseDouble(avg);
           }
        } 

        catch (Exception ex){
           System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
        } 

        //some exception handling
        finally{
           if (rs != null)  {
              try {
                 rs.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {}
                 rs = null;
              }

           if (pstmt != null) {
              try {
                pstmt.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {}
                pstmt = null;
              }

           if (currentCon != null) {
              try {
                 currentCon.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }

                currentCon = null;
           }
        }

          return monthRating;
```

Is that anything need to add into it so that it can be run in eclipse?

Comment: Please show your table

Comment: What does you connection string to the database look like?

Comment: Check your table `create` statement

Comment: Here is my java. @ConradLotz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Rating as `rs.getString("Rating")` while Rating has no Alias in the sql statement while being used in aggregation. Just add an alias

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) AS Rating ....
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you're not defining a name for the column you're retrieving:

```
select AVG(Rating) from ...
```

So, when you execute this:

```
rs.getString("Rating")
```

You get an exception. Change the query to:

```
select AVG(Rating) AS Rating from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
monthRating.add(rs.getString("Rating"));
```

You are fetching `Rating` column from `resultSet` but *query* has `AVG(Rating)` as column name so change it to,

```
monthRating.add(rs.getString("AVG(Rating)");
```